# Handling redirects when parsing urls

Tags: java, jsoup

Using the following code with jsoup will check if a url is status code 200 or not for parsing..but for example if a site redirects such as http://google.com to https://www.google.com(or even sometimes redirects to the .co.uk version) how can I use this redirect version instead of just ignoring it?

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect(Link).followRedirects(false).execute();
                         System.out.println(response.statusCode() + " : " + response.url());


                         if (200 == response.statusCode()) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirects are followed by default. 
See here for more information: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-check-redirect-url/

Response response = Jsoup.connect(Link).execute(); should do the trick